# How we schedule Azure Data Factory Pipeline only for first 5 days of every month

Tags: azure-data-factory

How we schedule  Trigger in  Azure Data Factory  for Pipeline only   first 5 days of every month

```
Month  Day Day Day Day Day
Jan     1  2    3  4   5
Feb     1  2    3  4   5  
........................
DEC     1  2    3  4  5
```

Answer (score 2):

- Create new Trigger and select schedule for trigger type.
- In recurrence, select to run every 1 month.
- In Advanced recurrence options, select the days of the month to execute the pipeline.

[image]